# Setting a max value for integer in android

Tags: java, android, integer

In my code I implement myint++ on swipe up and myint-- on swipe down.  But, I want to keep myint from exceeding certain values i.e. I don't want the value of myint to go above 10 or below 0.  I cannot find how to accomplish this.  Any help is appreciated :)

```
    int navX = navPref.getInt("navXPref", 5);
    int navY = navPref.getInt("navYPref", 5);

    switch (direction) {

       case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT : navX++;
                                            prefEditor.putInt("navXPref", navX);
                                            prefEditor.apply();
                                                break;
  case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT : navX--;
                                            prefEditor.putInt("navXPref", navX);
                                            prefEditor.apply();
                                                 break;
  case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN : navY--;
                                            prefEditor.putInt("navYPref", navY);
                                            prefEditor.apply();
                                                 break;
  case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP : navY++;
                                        prefEditor.putInt("navYPref", navY);
                                        prefEditor.apply();
                                                 break;

  }
```

Comment: If you want to keep the data type as an int, you would have to do something like `if (navY < 0) { navY = 0; }`, otherwise, you would define navY as a different data type.

Comment: That's what I've been trying to implement, but where?  Would it go between navX++ and prefEditor.putInt...?

Comment: right after all the updates in your switch. The downside to what I recommended though, is that you would be inclined to refactor your code to apply the value after the bounds checking. The upside is that you probably will have less lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do an if statement?

```
  case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN : if(navY > 0)
                                            navY--;
                                        prefEditor.putInt("navYPref", navY);
                                        prefEditor.apply();
                                        break;
   case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP : if(navY < 10)
                                           navY++;
                                       prefEditor.putInt("navYPref", navY);
                                       prefEditor.apply();
                                       break;
```

Comment: Hahaha that's so simple... I'm a bit new to it all, and i was under the misinformed assumption that if statements had to be contained in try {}.  Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution:

```
switch (direction) {
    case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT : navX++; break;
    case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT : navX--; break;
    case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN : navY--; break;
    case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP : navY++; break;
} 
if (navX < 0) { navX = 0; }
if (navY < 0) { navY = 0; }
if (navX > 10) { navX = 10; }
if (navY > 10) { navY = 10; }
prefEditor.putInt("navXPref", navX);
prefEditor.apply();
prefEditor.putInt("navYPref", navY);
prefEditor.apply();
```